# Find all pdf-files with whitespace or umlauts in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, command

i'm not an shell-expert but i need a command which i can't find with my good friend google.

I'm searching for a command, that will output all files with spaces or umlauts in the filename and which are from a specific type, for example .pdf - It Should search in all subdirectories too.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you ask for Linux?

Comment: Yes Sorry! I'm on an Apache Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
printf "%s\n" **/!(+([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])).pdf
```

That pattern specifies (english) upper or lower case letters, numbers, and some punctuation are "valid" characters. Adjust to suit your files. Any file not named exclusively with these characters is matched.

Note that the hyphen is a special character in a bracket expression (the range operator). To match a literal hyphen, it must be the first or last character in the brackets.

If you want to do something with these files, use a for-loop:

```
for file in **/!(+([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])).pdf; do
    : do stuff with "$file" -- quotes are important
done
```